# iText 7 - Rotate text is not returning correct angle

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm using iText7 to produce a PDF and would like to rotate text. This is the code I have produced:

```
new Canvas(canvas, pdf, pagesize)
.ShowTextAligned("UK18-D12345678", 185, 8, TextAlignment.CENTER, 270);
```

This doesn't return an accurate 270 degree angle. See example below.
However when I set the angle to 300 this returns the string as expected in a vertical line.

[image: pdf screenshot]

My question is what is making iText not accurately produce a 270 degree angle for a line of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining an angle in degrees. The `ShowTextAligned()` method expects an angle in radians (see the [API docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/Canvas.html)). You should use 3π/2 radians instead of 270°.

You say that you get a vertical line when you pass `300` as a parameter. That's almost correct. 300 radians equals 17188.7 degrees, which visually corresponds with 268.7 degrees (that's indeed very close to 270, but not exactly).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.